# What does array of 1's mean in binary when reading

Tags: java, io, binary, ascii, filestream

Why do I get 32 digits of 1 when there is no more bytes to be read? When I use FileInput stream.
Shouldn't I get EOFException instead (like we get in **Object** or **Data** streams)?

I will demonstrate using simple read/write program.

```
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("a.txt");
            fileWriter.write('A');  //writes 'A' to file (a.txt)
            fileWriter.close();
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("a.txt");
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(fileInputStream.read()));//1000001
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(fileInputStream.read()));//11111111111111111111111111111111
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(fileInputStream.read()));//11111111111111111111111111111111
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(fileInputStream.read()));//11111111111111111111111111111111
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So in each read() I get 4 bytes of 1s. That goes in inifinity..
I thought I would get only byte value as 65 is 1000001 in binary. So 1 byte total.
Where do these other bytes come from? Do they really exist?

EDIT:
What is difference between these two values I get when I calculate? So why not just throw EOFException instead?
[image]

Comment: `11111111111111111111111111111111` is `-1` which i might suppose to be the binary representation of the EOF flag

Comment: I just calculated 32 1st from binary to decimal.Result is 4294967295. And then I also get Decimal from signed 2's complement: -1. What does that mean?

Comment: The larger number is an unsigned integer, the other one is a signed integer in the format that Java uses.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses a system called [2's complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed numbers in binary. In this system, the number -1 is represented with a bit pattern where all bits are 1. This is because adding 1 to a number where all bits are set gives you zero (thanks to  *overflow*).

So what you've observed is that `fileInputStream.read()` is returning -1, which is how it indicates the state of "end of file, there is nothing more to read".

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs! https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()

```
read()
Returns:
    the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.
```

Comment: Yeah I know that, but 8 1st to decimal is not -1, but 4294967295. Try in in calculator..

Comment: In Java, ints are signed. 32 one bits is -1. Your calculator may be assuming an unsigned int.

Comment: Hmm I'll check it out. Makes sense. None than less, why does it behave like this do you know? Why not throw Exception like streams we chain to FileInputStream do? If I were to loop it, I would end up in endless loop..

Comment: @AnaMaria: exceptions are for error conditions. Reaching the end of an `InputStream` is not (necessarily) an error condition.

Comment: It is not error of an InputStream, but it is an error of a DataStream.. Kinda made me even more confused :(

Comment: It's an old API patterned after C's [getchar()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar). Returning a sentinel value is more efficient than throwing an exception, but people generally frown upon in-band errors these days.  The Java API designers might do it differently today. Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: @Ana DataInputStream and ObjectInputStream use EOFException because they read larger data structures than individual bytes. If the file ends in the middle of a "thing", the stream needs to have a way to communicate that, and that's when they throw an EOFException